# How to fetch and attach .htm files in Perl?

Tags: perl

Consider this code:

```
    $ENV{HTTP_proxy} = $proxy_url;
    my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => "http://xxxxx.htm");
    my $where = $ff->fetch();
    my $file = $ff->file;
    my $error=$ff->error();
    delete $ENV{HTTP_proxy};
    $jira->attach_file_to_issue($src_issue, $file);
    print "URL: $file attached to $src_issue key \n .......................\n";
    unlink $file;
```

I want to fetch and attach a .htm file from a remote system. I'm using the [File::Fetch](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Fetch.html) CPAN module. I'm not able to attach the file:

> ERROR: Could not stat tmpfile 'C:/Users/jira123/Desktop/New folder/Linking_scripts/FW:L2_PM_on_11qpe24.htm-8584': No such file or directory at C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 922.

How do I attach .htm files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code **$where** is the name of the locally stored file which has the content fetched from the given URL (provided fetch was successful). The local file ($where) is stored in the current working directory (i.e. the directory from which you launched the script from). 
So the code that attaches the file should be something like below:

```
$jira->attach_file_to_issue($src_issue,$where);
```

You are specifying **$file** as an attachment and as per the documentation of the module [File::Fetch](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/File-Fetch-0.46/lib/File/Fetch.pm), 
**$file** corresponds to name of the remote file.

Comment: thanks for reply sateesh. But with same code I can attach all other type of files, Only I'm unable to attach .htm files. Code is not fetching any content remote .htm file. Please help me

Comment: And also code is unable to fetch content of .htm files, just it is creating file with no content

Comment: After the check you do query for error, check that error and see if fetch was successful or not. The fetch might have failed due to any reason.

Comment: again I'm getting same error. Its is not fetching anything from remote .htm file.